# Como executar um método até o retorno ser verdadeiro(true) ? Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma condição onde o FORM principal só abre quando o carregador estiver conectado.

Como faço para ficar atualizando a porcentagem da bateria no FORM principal ?

Como faço para ficar a monitorando caso ele remova o carregador depois de passar pela verificação ?

**Método que busca a porcentagem da bateria:**

```
 public static int GetPercentBattery() {
        int percent = 0;          

        try {

            ManagementObjectSearcher s2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in s2.Get()) {                   
                
                percent = Int32.Parse(mo["EstimatedChargeRemaining"].ToString().Trim());
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            string mensagem = "Erro no teste da Bateria: " + e.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(mensagem);                
            throw new Exception("Erro no teste da Bateria");
        }

        return percent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu tenteria algo recursivo. Segue um exemplo não testado de como eu faria, valide a idéia e modifique até chegar no resultado que você espera...

```
public static bool GetPercentBattery() 
{
    int percent = 0;          
    try {
        ManagementObjectSearcher s2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery");
        ManagementObject mo in s2.Get();                   
        percent = Int32.Parse(mo["EstimatedChargeRemaining"].ToString().Trim());
        if(percent == 100)
            return true;
        else
            GetPercentBattery();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        string mensagem = "Erro no teste da Bateria: " + e.Message;
        Console.WriteLine(mensagem);                
        throw new Exception("Erro no teste da Bateria");
    }
    return false;
}
```